# Magento move attributes to top of product view page

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes

Quick question, my attributes are now displayed at the bottom of the page below (long) description. But I want them to be displayed at the top of the page below the add to cart button.

I searched view.phtml, but I can't figure out how attributes.phtml is called. I also considered moving it to the topo with CSS but that will give a messy result with different numbers of attributes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way the attributes displayed in the product view pay may vary a lot from theme to theme.
But if you are using a theme similar to the default theme (before 1.9) here is what you can do.

Look for this in the `catalog.xml` of your theme:

```
<block type="catalog/product_view_attributes" name="product.attributes" as="additional" template="catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml">
    <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
</block>
```

and remove the line `<action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>`. That's the line responsible for placing the block in a specific group.

Then edit `catalog/product/view.phtml` and add this line where you want the attributes to be displayed.

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('additional')?>
```

If you are using a theme similar to the rwd theme (the 1.9 default one) you should do this:

```
<block type="catalog/product_view_attributes" name="product.attributes" as="additional" template="catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml">
    <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
    <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Additional Information</value></action>
</block>
```

You should to the same thing as above. But in addition also remove this line

```
<action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Additional Information</value></action>
```